# Producer/2consumers implementation with multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, producer-consumer

I want to implement "producer/two consumers" functionality.

**Producer:** scans directories recursively and adds directory information to some storage (I guess `Queue<>`)

**Consumer 1:** retrieves data about directory and writes it to XML-file.

**Consumer 2:** retrieves data about directory and add it to TreeNode.

So both (1 and 2) consumers have to work with a same data. Because if one of consumers call `Dequeue()`, the other one will miss this data.

The only idea I have - is to make 2 different `Queue<>` and Producer will fill them both with a same data. Then each consumer will work with different `Queue` object.

I hope you'll advise something more attractive

Comment: This might help you .http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147(v=vs.110).aspx and for Blocking collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx. .NET 4 and above supports producer consumer pattern

Comment: Also, remember that if you push a reference to the same object into two `Queues`, the memory consumption due to multiple queues is minimal. You are duplicating the reference, not the actual data contained in the object.

Comment: Also, [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), depending on whether your application needs [back-pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpressure_Routing)

Comment: Simple: it is not a producer consumer case. You have two task that can ( if they really can ) works concurrently

Comment: Can you combine the two consumers into one? I.e one consumer writes the XML and the. Adds the tree node?

Answer (score 1):

LMAX Disruptor is one solution to this problem.

Article: http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

Illustration of the single-producer, multithreaded consumer ring buffer: http://martinfowler.com/articles/images/lmax/disruptor.png

It is assumed that you will need good - nearly expert level - knowledge of how atomic instructions and lock-free algorithms work on your target platform.

---

The description below is different from LMAX - I adapted it to the OP's scenario.

The underlying structure could be either a ring buffer (fixed-capacity), or a lock-free linked list (unlimited capacity, but only available on platforms that supports certain kinds of multi-word atomic instructions).

The producer will just push stuff to the front.

Each consumer keeps an iterator to the item that they are processing. Each consumer advances its own iterator, at each's own pace.

Besides the consumers, there is also a trailing garbage collector which will also try to advance, but it will not advance past any of the consumer's iterators. Thus, it will eventually clean up items that both consumers have finished processing, and only those items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ZeroMQ, which has this functionality built into it (and a lot more) -
http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html

The above example is with Python code, but there are .NET bindings -
http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr